# Почему используя "in" происходит копирование струтуры?

Tags: c#, .net

Я не понял совершенно принцип работы "in" в C#.

```
public static void ChangePersonName(in IPerson person, string name)
{
    person.Name = name;
}

public static void ChangeValue(in int value)
{
    value = 20;
}
```

Почему первый метод не вызывает ошибки компилятора, хотя я пытаюсь изменить структуру внутри метода, что противоречит "in", а вот второй метод сразу выдает ошибку, что я меняю, хотя передаю по "in".
Ну окей, может я в первом не могу как бы параметру присвоить новую структуру, а вот свойства менять могу, но тогда в таком случае после срабатывания метода свойства не поменяются, но как так, я ведь передаю по ссылке структуру? Я так понял происходит копирования, но ведь "in" передает параметр по ссылке. В общем я запутался...

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/

Comment: [Reference parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#reference-parameters) - объяснено различие ref, out, in. [Tutorial: Reduce memory allocations with ref safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/performance/ref-tutorial) - на примере показано использование.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `in` не влияет на `.Name` и всё что внутри передаваемого объекта или структуры. Он влияет только на саму `person`.

`in` копирует структуру или ссылку на объект как если бы вы ничего не указали, но делает её только для чтения. Почему так: `in` гарантирует что аргумент не будет  изменён даже за пределами метода. При передаче по рефу такое было бы невозможно.

Если нужно по рефу передавать неизменяемую, пишите `readonly ref`.

[Документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters#reference-parameters)

Comment: а в чем еще различие при вызове метода указывать in, и не указывать?

Comment: и то есть получается что in все таки копирует параметры, так?

Comment: @Андрей если не указывать, то можно переприсвоить аргумент. Да, копирует.